# How do I backup data to azure blob from azure cosmos db during a specific stage?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have Azure cosmos DB account what I want to do is backup data which is one month old from azure cosmos DB to Azure blob storage using my node app. I have already created pipeline and have triggered it by using create run pipeline API for Nodejs (using Azure data factory). But I am not able to figure out how to make the pipeline selective for data which is one month old from the current date. Any suggestions for that?

**EDIT**: Actually I want to run the API daily so that it backs up data which is one month old. For example, let's say I get 100 entries today in my cosmos DB, so the pipeline should select data from current date - 30 days and should back it up so that at any point my Azure cosmos DB has data for recent 30 days only and rest are backed up to Azure blob.

Answer (score 2):

Just a supplement to @David's answer here.If you mean Cosmos DB SQL API, it has automatic backup mechanism based on this link:[Automatic and online backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore#automatic-and-online-backups).

> With Azure Cosmos DB, not only your data, but also the backups of your
>   data are highly redundant and resilient to regional disasters. The
>   automated backups are currently taken every four hours and at any
>   point of time, the latest two backups are stored. If you have
>   accidentally deleted or corrupted your data, you should contact Azure
>   support within eight hours so that the Azure Cosmos DB team can help
>   you restore the data from the backups.

However,you cannot access this backup directly. Azure Cosmos DB will use this backup only if a backup restore is initiated.

But the document provides two [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore#options-to-manage-your-own-backups) to manage your own backups.

- 1.Use Azure Data Factory to move data periodically to a storage of your choice.
- 2.Use Azure Cosmos DB change feed to read data periodically for full backups, as well as for incremental changes, and store it in your own
  storage.

You could use trigger the copy activity in ADF to transfer data in the schedule.If you want to filter data by date,you could learn about [_ts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates) in cosmos db which represents the latest modified time of data.

Comment: I'm actually very new to Azure. The data I'm working upon already has a date field in it. I want the data which is one month old from the current date to be backed up to Azure blob using the pipeline from ADF, can you provide more information about how can I do that? Thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what pipeline you're referring to. That said: Cosmos DB doesn't have any built-in backup tools. You'd need to select and copy this data programmatically.

If using the MongoDB API, you could pass a query parameter to the `mongoexport` command-line tool (to serve as your date filter), but you'd still need to run `mongoexport` from your VM, write to a local directory, then copy to blob storage (I don't know if you can install/run MongoDB tools in something like Azure Functions or a DevOps pipeline).

Comment: Actually, I have created a pipeline to transfer data from azure cosmos DB to Azure blob storage using azure data factory. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities

Comment: That's great that you did that, as Data Factory is a very versatile tool. if Data Factory was what you were referring to, in your original question, when you mentioned "pipeline", it would be really helpful to clarify that in your question (and in your tags). That would have really changed the focus of the question to be specific to Data Factory.